# Clarifications about a proof of (the measurable Riemann) mapping theorem in Hubbard's book on Teichmuller theory,

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, teichmuller-theory

On page 151 of Hubbard's book, the author is proving the following theorem( Prop.4.6.2 ):

Suppose $\mu$ is a real analytic function on a domain $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Then every $z \in U$ has a neighbourhood $V$ in $U$ such that there is a real analytic function $f: V \to \mathbb{C}$ that is a homomorphism onto its image and satisfies the Beltrami equation:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = \mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
$$

Now, he approaches the problem in the following way. First, he rewrites the Beltrami equation in the following form:
$$
(1-\mu(x,y))\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i(1+\mu(x,y))\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0
$$

Doing this, he considers that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$.The above equation is considered in a neighbourhood $W$ of $z_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where $\mu$ is assumed analytical. Now there are some things that he says that I don't understand.

- He considers the following differential equation:
  $$
  \frac{dy}{dx} = i\frac{1+\mu(x,y(x))}{1-\mu(x,y(x))}
  $$
  But I don't know if there is a theorem in Complex analysis which is analogous of Picard's about ODEs
- He says that the functions which satisfy Beltrami equation are functions that are constant on the solution of the ODE. I thought about differentiating the equation $(x,f(x))$ along the curve of the solution of ODE. However, he than says that this is a brilliant idea of Gauss and I don't see what is idea or why should it be brilliant. I don't see how solving this ODE gives us solutions of the initial problem.
- He than uses inverse function theorem for the function which is $y$ on the line $x = x_0$ and says:
  $$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) = -i \frac{1 + \mu(x_0,y_0)}{1 - \mu(x_0,y_0)}
  $$

He says that the above number is not real( another way of saying that it is not zero? ) and applies inverse function theorem and says that f induces local diffeomorphism between $W \cap \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$. What I don't see is why is it $W \cap \mathbb{R}^2$ and not just $W$?